# How can I find photos in a folder that could be stitched together in a panorama?

Tags: panorama, hugin

I've got lots of photos (sorted in directories with maybe 50-200 shots in each), and many times I've taken a series of photos I wanted to stitch together into a panorama and then I forgot about them when I got home.

Is there a tool I could run on my directory of photos that would detect photos that can possibly be stitched into a panoramas for me? I'm mainly a Linux user, but could use some other OS if it made this easier.

PTBatcherGUI (in Hugin) has a "*Search Directory For.... Images*" function which is almost there - it seems to detect groups of photos based on the camera and time between them, but it picks up loads of false positives (e.g. multiple shots of the same thing).
Ideally there would be something that took PTBatcherGUI's results, aligned them, and then only passed on the ones where alignment worked and created an image that was bigger than the source.

Is there a tool that does that? It'd be great to be able to pull up some of my 'lost' panoramas!

Comment: This sounds quite niche... Does PTBatcherGUI return a list of the photo groups as a text file?

Comment: No text file as far as I can see but it will export to panotools project files. There's a menu where groups are listed and you can see thumbnails of each photo in the group, but when I do a year and there are over 100 possible groups, it gets tedious quite fast!

Is it niche to want to be able to find panoramas though? I'd have thought it was quite common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a tool that does this out of the box.

As PTBatcherGUI can export a project file, you could feed that into a [command line stitcher](https://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_scripting_in_a_nutshell).

You can then check what the stitcher returns in terms of errors or return codes and store that value per picture group.

- If it's an error it might be safe to assume that the picture group is not a panorama.
- If the CLI tool returns a succes code, the images are likely a panorama and you can then properly stitch them using the tool of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! yes, I guess this is the best bet - just allow it to create project files for all the panoramas, and then ditch all the ones where the command-line tools fail to create anything.